# How to configure a non-trivial list view in share point

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list. It has items with properties A, B, C, D, and E. I want to create a view that would filter the items like this....

```
WHERE (a = 1 AND b = 2) AND (c = 3 OR d = 4 OR e = 5)
```

Sharepoint appears to flatten this out to

```
WHERE (a = 1 AND b = 2 AND c = 3 OR d = 4 OR e = 5)
```

And gives me results I do not want. IRL, this is to view work currently in progress (A and B - text field) that is assigned to a set of developers (C, D, and E - People).

Does anyone have a reasonable solution to this? Computed columns doesnt seem to allow for the data type "People". Is there any other formulae or trickery I can code in to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need XSLT View or webpart.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I totally forgot about **CAML views**. It is a lot more suitable solution. 
Read [this article](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/customizing-the-user-experience-of-sharepoint-lists-custom-list-forms-and-caml-views-part-3-of-6) for example

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into that, but it looks like its more about customizing the display and not the results.

Comment: XSLT - yes, CAML view - no. Using CAML view you can define complex conditions using simple XML-based query language.

Comment: Working with this viewer (http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/), and hacking around with the page source a bit I was able to get done what I needed. Thanks for the push in the correct direction.